# Canon 7D - shutter Will Not Fire and Menus Disabled When Auto-Focus Is On

Tags: autofocus, shutter, canon-7d

When I set the shooting mode to anything but automatic(eg., M, TV, SV, c1, c2, c3),  and the lens is on the camera and is set to auto focus, I cannot fire the shutter or view any of the screens.

- Works fine in auto shooting mode
- Issue only happens when not shotting in auto mode such as M, TV, AV, C1, C3, C3, B
- Focus is single shot not servo
- Pulled & replaced both batteries.
- Firmware is current version.
- No "event" started the issue i.e., was not dropped, did not get wet, etc.
- I reset the camera to all default settings.
- Same issue with all lenses
- Problem goes away when I remove the lens.
- Problem goes away whenI select manual focus on the lens.

It seems like it might be related to the connection between the bode and lens. Contacts look fine, I cleanered them just in case.

I have seen similar posts on other forums but none had any solutions that worked.

A y ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: Did you get focus confirmation when you try to take a photo?

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, the camera is failing to achieve focus.  Some things to try:

1. Replace the camera's clock battery.  The whole "disabled screens" thing makes me suspect something bizarre like that.
2. Hold the button down longer, making sure that focusing is confirmed before trying to take the shot.
3. Try changing which autofocus points are selected.  If there's nothing under the focus points, it won't focus; in full auto mode, it probably always uses every focus point, which could mask a bizarre focus point setting.

If none of those things help, given that multiple lenses are behaving badly, my money would be on something wrong with the focusing sensor.  Unfortunately, the cost of repairing it would be several times as much as a used replacement 7D would cost on eBay, so if you can't get it working, this might be the right time to upgrade your camera body.

Comment: If the OP is going to replace it I'd suggest a used 7D Mark II, which is a much better camera than the original 7D in so many ways, but especially with AF accuracy and shot-to-shot consistency. Better high ISO/low light performance as well, and the 7D II has flicker reduction for when one is shooting under flickering light sources. I've shot extensively with the 7D from early 2012 to mid-2015, and with the 7D II from 2015 to present (200,000+ shutter actuations). They're worlds apart.

Comment: Agreed.  I definitely didn't intend to suggest that buying another original 7D is a good idea — just saying that the amount you could get for selling it after repairing it would be less than the repair cost, so fixing it is basically throwing money away.  If it's just the clock battery, it's worth ten minutes and two bucks to fix it, but if it is anything else, I'd probably sell it for parts and use that towards something more modern.

Answer (score 0):

It does not sound like it is related to lens/body contacts; if it were then it would almost certainly affect the fully automatic mode as well. I would do a full factory reset.